Does temporal difference prediction error decrease as it back-propagates towards CS in simple Pavlovian conditioning?
I've been working on a simulation of value and prediction error change according to the temporal difference model during Pavlovian trace conditioning in R and I've been getting some unexpected outputs with prediction error as it moves back towards the CS. More specifically, while most papers I've read show TD prediction error moving from the US back towards the CS across trials without decreasing (see Fig. 1B Starkweather & Uchida 2021), my simulations show the prediction error peak decreasing as it moves back towards the CS and then decreasing every trial after the TD error peak hits the CS onset. This is happening regardless of how I adjust the model (gamma, alpha, CS onset/duration, US onset/duration, etc.). However, the shape of my value function seems to be consistent what I've seen in the above mentioned paper and others.
Is my simulation correct (and these papers are just keeping the TD peak the same at US and CS to make a more clean graphic) or is there an issue with my model?
For reference, my error prediction calculation is Rt + gamma* V(St+1) - V(St) where Rt is the intensity of the reward (I set this arbitrarily at 1), V(St+1) is the value calculated for the state following the current state in the previous trial, V(St) is the value calculated in the same state in the previous trial, and gamma is the temporal discounting factor.
I've also included images of my simulations of value and prediction error.
